# Can't create SSD persistent disk during free trial on Google Compute Engine (gce)

Tags: cassandra, google-compute-engine, solid-state-drive

I'm trying to evaluate a performance of Cassandra cluster on Google Compute Engine.

I've successfully created cluster with Standard Persistent Disk. Now trying to create SSD Persistent Disk but I do not have such option for my project:

```
gcloud compute disk-types list
NAME        ZONE           VALID_DISK_SIZES
pd-standard europe-west1-d 10GB-10240GB
pd-standard asia-east1-a   10GB-10240GB
pd-standard asia-east1-b   10GB-10240GB
pd-standard asia-east1-c   10GB-10240GB
pd-standard europe-west1-a 10GB-10240GB
pd-standard europe-west1-b 10GB-10240GB
pd-standard europe-west1-c 10GB-10240GB
pd-standard us-central1-a  10GB-10240GB
pd-standard us-central1-c  10GB-10240GB
pd-standard us-central1-b  10GB-10240GB
pd-standard us-central1-f  10GB-10240GB
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Update

Recreated a project. When I'm trying to create Cassandra cluster with SSD I get:

```
Replica cassandra-coord-1713 failed with status PERMANENTLY_FAILING: Replica State changed to PERMANENTLY_FAILING. Replica was unhealthy 2 consecutive times.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some restrictions in the quotas that you have during your free trial. One of them includes the SSD disk space which you will not have.  In order to be entitled to quota increases, the account needs to be upgraded first to a paid version

[1] https://cloud.google.com/free-trial/.